# Lua Rock Paper Scissors Scoring System

Tags: lua

I am trying to create a scoring system for my RPS program, which is going great until it prints the final score, which always returns 0.

During the game, if the player/bot wins, 1 point will be added to their score. But when the game ends and the final score is printed, it resets. How do I stop it from resetting?

**UPDATE:**

*I've formatted my code a little better to hopefully make it easier to read, but the original problem still stands. With this, the final score is still 0, I don't understand why. Please help.*

Code:

```
local p = "Paper"
local s = "Scissors"
local pw = "Player wins!\n"
local bw = "Bot wins!\n"
local t = "Tie!\n"
local hands = {r, p, s}
local ps = 0 -- Player Score
local bs = 0 -- Bot Score

function _G.addPs() -- Adds 1 to Player Score
    _G.ps = ps + 1
end

function _G.addBs() -- Adds 1 to Bot Score
    _G.bs = bs + 1
end

print("Type 'stop' to stop the game.\n")

function _G.rps()
    while true do
        print("Rock, Paper, or Scissors:")
        local player = io.read()
        print()
        print("Player chooses " .. player .. "!\n")
        local bot = (hands[math.random(#hands)])
        print("Bot chooses " .. bot .. "!\n")
   
        if player == r and bot == p then
            print(bw)
            addBs()
        elseif player == p and bot == r then
            print(pw)
            addPs()
        elseif player == r and bot == s then
            print(pw)
            addPs()
        elseif player == s and bot == r then
            print(bw)
            addBs()
        elseif player == p and bot == s then
            print(bw)
            addBs()
        elseif player == s and bot == p then
            print(pw)
            addPs()
        elseif player == r and bot == r then
            print(t)
        elseif player == p and bot == p then
            print(t)
        elseif player == s and bot == s then
            print(t)
        elseif player == "stop" then
            print("Stopping. . .")
            break
        elseif player ~= hands then
            print("Error: Player did not choose valid option(Rock; Paper; Scissors; stop)\nContinuing. . .\n")
        end
    end
end

rps()

local fs = ("Final Score:\nPlayer Score: " .. ps .. "\nBot Score: "  .. bs) -- Final Score
print()
print(fs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else answered it for me. It was because I was using _G.ps instead of ps in my functions. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
local fs = ("Final Score: \n Player Score: " .. ps .. "\n Bot Score: "  .. bs)
```

This line creates a string value. It uses the values of `ps` and `bs` at the moment of creation and this won't change until the end of the game.

This is the real world equivalent of writing the final score of 0 : 0 on a piece of paper befor a game begins. When you read it after the game it is still the same sentence.

A few more hints on your code:

Your indentation is a bit off. You usually do it like this:

```
if condition1 then
  -- do stuff
elseif condition 2 then
  -- do stuff
else
  -- do stuff
end
```

Also it is `elseif`, not `else if` in Lua. Not sure why you write it that way.

Also you offer the user to continue but your code will terminate anyway as that option is already outside the loop.

Comment: Apologies, should've mentioned I'm new to Lua. I appreciate all the feedback, and I understand your reasoning, but if I try to put the 'fs' variable after the loop and print it, it still prints 0. I've tried both 'ps, bs' and '_G.ps, _G.bs' variables, they print 1 but none after that.